# How to include the "new" routes in Rails 5 API mode [The action 'show' could not be found]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actioncontroller

currently I'm getting this error

```
The action 'show' could not be found for Api::V1::ImagesController
```

my routes file looks like this

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
        ...
        resources :images
        ...
    end
end
```

I can also see that the resources method has not created the new endpoint as per [the docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time)

Ive done this for the time being, but I would love to know if there is a cleaner fix:

```
class Api::V1::ImagesController < Api::BaseController

  def show
    new if params[:id] == "new"
  end

  def new
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :images do
      get :new
    end
  end
end
```

Or if you want to do this to multiple resources use a routing concern:

```
concern :has_new do
  get :new
end

namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :images, concerns: :has_new
    resources :videos, concerns: :has_new
  end
end
```

I don't think there is actually an option to re-add the `new` and `edit` routes to the `resources` call when your application is running in api only mode. And you would have to monkeypatch [ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Resources](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html) to change the behavior if you wanted to do this for all your routes.

Comment: I tried this but still the show action is being triggered for ruby 3.0 and rails 7.0

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to have a show route?  If you do, then you need to add the show method.  You don't have to actually have anything in there.

`def show; end`

If you don't want to include the show route and still use the resources helper, you could always use `only` in your resource.  `resources :images, only: [:new]`